# D3: Spiral plot Error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I had used following link for spiral plot: 
https://bl.ocks.org/arpitnarechania/027e163073864ef2ac4ceb5c2c0bf616 
I'm playing around with the code and I am facing one issue when I change the currentDate to currentDate.toDateString() when it is reading the data i.e

```
...
var someData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + i);
  someData.push({
    date: currentDate.toDateString(),
    value: Math.random(),
    group: currentDate.getMonth()
  });

}
...
```

The issue that I'm facing is, after changing `currentdate` it is not able to display the spiral chart.
I check that it is storing the data in the someData array but while creating "rect" there is a function used for "x" axis that is having some issue when it calling the timeScale(d.date) function.

I am not getting why this is happening. 
Even though when I try to use another data in place of currentdate it is not displaying chart.

Kindly please help me on this.

Thanks
Amit Sah

Comment: Hey, it's my spiral plot, good to see someone using it!  Your problem is that the code expects `date` to be a **Date object**.  You are converting it to a **string**.  Why are you changing it?  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Hey, @Mark Yes this visualization is good.I, want to know one thing first that this visualization code will work only for Date Object? and the next thing is I am trying to make this visualization work for any kind of data.I tried it for some data like date is in 04/03/2017 format by taking external data for testing purpose but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Mark please help me on this.

Comment: `I am trying to make this visualization work for any kind of data` is way too vague.  Be specific.  For instance, to change the date format just change the `tF` variable to the format you want.  Something like [this change here](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/7c01f895faa03e88979a53c303f53fa9)

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.I mean that, I am taking the external data that contains "Date" value which is in "04/03/2017"  format.And when I use this data then the spiral plot is not displaying.So, my end goal is that If I use any kind of data( say like "region", "country") that should work with this.

Comment: @Mark Sorry for not being specific.I mean that I am taking the external data that contains "Date" value which is in "04/03/2017"  format.And when I use this data then the spiral plot is not displaying.So, my end goal is that If I use any kind of data( say like "region", "country") that should work with this.If not at least time period related data(like date,month,year)
Does the " d3.scaleTime() " function is used only for taking Date object data? Instead of this what can I use to allow this spiral chart to take any kind of data.